# Splitting field of $X^3+X+1$ and $X^3-3$

Tags: solution-verification, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $f=X^3-3\in\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $E_f/k$ is an extension, where $k$ is a field. I want to find $E_f$ such that $f$ decomposes in $E_f[X]$ and $E_f=k[a_1,...,a_n]$, where $a_1,...,a_n$ are the roots of $f\in E[X]$.

- How should I approach if $k=\mathbb{Q}$? The roots of $f$ in $\mathbb{C}$ are $\sqrt[3]{3},-\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}}{2}+i\frac{3^{\frac{5}{5}}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}}{2}-i\frac{3^{\frac{5}{5}}}{2}$. And so, I may take $E_f=\mathbb{Q}\left[\sqrt[3]{3},-\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}}{2}+i\frac{3^{\frac{5}{5}}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}}{2}-i\frac{3^{\frac{5}{5}}}{2}\right]$, correct?
- If $k=\mathbb{F}_3$, I may take $E_f=\mathbb{F}_3$ because $f$ becomes $X^3$ and it is already factored. Is this correct?
- If $k=\mathbb{F}_5$, then I don't really know how to proceed.

But if, for example, $k=\mathbb{F}_2$ and $f=X^3+X+1$, then I take $\alpha=X+(f(X))\in\mathbb{F}_2[X]/(f(X))$. And so, $\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$ is a field, $\alpha^3=X+1$ and $f=(X+\alpha)(X^2+aX+b)$. I find that $a=\alpha, b=1+\alpha$. I list the elements $c\alpha^2+d\alpha +e$ of $\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$ ($c,d,e\in\mathbb{F}_2$) because they are just $8$. Finally, I note that $\alpha^2,1+\alpha^2\in\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$ are roots of $X^2+\alpha X+1+\alpha^2$. Hence, $f$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$ and I take $E_f=\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha)$.

Now, I don't think this method is very useful for the third example because we would have to check $5^3=125$ elements of $\mathbb{F}_5(\alpha)$. Is there a quicker way to solve this?

I appreciate any help. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 already has a cube root in $\mathbb{F}_5$, so $X^3 - 3$ can be divided by a linear polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_5$ to give a quadratic polynomial, and then you just need a quadratic extension to split it.

Comment: So, I have $X^3-3=(X-2)(X^2+2X+4)\in\mathbb{F}_5$.  Now, following the same method, I have $X^2+2X+4=(X-\alpha)(X+a)$. I find that $a=2+\alpha$ and that $4\alpha+3$, an element of $\mathbb{F}_5(\alpha)$, is a root of $X+a$. Hence, $f$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_5(\alpha)$?

Comment: You can solve this like any quadratic equation $\alpha = \frac{-2\pm \sqrt{2^2 - 4*4}}{2} = 4\pm 3 \sqrt{3}$.  So $\mathbb{F}_5(\sqrt{3})$ is a field of 25 elements that splits the polynomial.